# Javascript Submit only working with id

Tags: javascript, php, html

So i have this problem. This form has a date type input that goes to another php function that i didn't posted because it works fine, there's only one thing that doesn't work. You can see `dateform` is an id so when i choose a date it only goes throw all the process with the first row (it's inside a while loop). I know the problem, `dateform` has to be class but if i change id for class it doesn't work.

The following code is the one it works (only in first row). I changed it for `$(".dateform")` and `class="dateform"` but still.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dateinput").change(function(){
        console.log("Submiting form");                
        $("#dateform").submit();
    });
</script>
```

html

```
<form id="dateform" action="' . date($connection) . '" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="order" value="' . $row['order'] . '">
    <input type="hidden" name="a_date" value="' . $a['id'] . '">
    <input class="dateinput" type="date" name="rDate" value="' . $row['r_view'] . '">
    </form>
```

Comment: write `  $(this)` instead of `.$(".dateinput").`

Comment: Already did it.

Comment: so what problem

Comment: invalidates all the process

Comment: I don't get it. Where is your while loop, your posted code does not seem to have any clientside problem?

Comment: @Bhargav — That will bind the change event handler to the `window` object. `$("#dateform")` will still locate the unique element with that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a global selector to find the form associated with the specific input you are dealing with.

"Search the document for the element with the (unique) id blah" will always give you the same result.

If you did change the id to a class, then you would get **all** the forms and you still wouldn't know which one was relevant.

You need to start from something associated with the event (i.e. `this` … the select element which triggered the event) and then find a *relationship* from it to the element you are trying to find.

In this case you are looking for the form associated with the form control, and there is a standard property for that.

```
$(this.form).submit();
```